# QApplication(sys.argv) is giving index out of range for sys.argv[1] in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pyside

I have a python code which takes a file name as input and parse the data present in the report and gives output in GUI window. When I am trying to parse the report I am getting index out of range error. I know that the error is because of  sys.argv[1] argument. But am not able to figure out why sys.argv[1] is not able to store the filename.

I have un-installed all the python modules and I have un-installed the parser which was throwing the error.

I have also removed python path from environment variable and also from the registry and then reinstalled the python and my parser software.

I have also deleted data from USERS\%Username%\Appdata

After reinstalling both(python2.7.3 and my third party software) I have also made change in the registry entry **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python26.exe\shell\open\command** to 
**C:>ftype Python26.File="C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %***
Even I have added the python path under environment variable.

This is working fine on other machines and also it was working fine on my machine until, the day I uninstalled python 3.xx( i was having both 3.xx and 2.7.3) from my machine.

I am getting error in  **file_name = file_path[0]** this line
I am not able to understand if sys.arg[1] is not present then it should throw error in **file_path = sys.argv[1:]** this line. But how it is able to store the string in **file_path** as lists size is only 1.

Can somebody help me out in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
file_path = sys.argv[1:]
open_window = TelematicsFileViewer()
open_window.show()
file_name = file_path[0]
path = file_path[1]
open_window.parsed_file_out(file_name, path)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If sys.argv is length 1, sys.argv[1:] will not throw an error, it will just return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

As @flyingmeatball says it will return empty list [], which then causes an error when you reference first element of the empty list.

So could could add in a check as high up in your script as possible to exit with error code 1 to stop the rest of the script from running.

```
if len(sys.argv) < 4: # require file name and at least 2 args
    print 'Include at least two arguments and retry.'
    sys.exit(1)
```